# 404 on page refresh of MySQL query with NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

So i have a website that runs on express with some MySQL queries to load photo albums.
The problem is that when i go to /photo everything works fine but if I refresh the page then i get a 404 NOT FOUND. Same if i go first to /photo then on another url and back to /photo.
The problem happens regardless if it's in prod or dev but only happens on my server, never on local.

here's what i get :

```
NotFoundError: Not Found
    at /home/vincdgfq/sachalebas/app.js:53:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/vincdgfq/nodevenv/sachalebas/9/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/vincdgfq/nodevenv/sachalebas/9/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/vincdgfq/nodevenv/sachalebas/9/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/vincdgfq/nodevenv/sachalebas/9/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/vincdgfq/nodevenv/sachalebas/9/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/vincdgfq/nodevenv/sachalebas/9/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at next (/home/vincdgfq/nodevenv/sachalebas/9/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (/home/vincdgfq/nodevenv/sachalebas/9/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/vincdgfq/nodevenv/sachalebas/9/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
```

If i remove all my error handlers i just get a

```
CANNOT GET /501.shtml
```

website can be found here : https://sachalebas.com/photo

Thanks in advance if anyone has got any idea where i should look for with this error i'm totally lost.

EDIT:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

require('./controllers/userController');

const oneYear = 60 * 1000 * 60 * 24 * 7;
const xssFilter = require('x-xss-protection');
const noSniff = require('dont-sniff-mimetype');
require('dotenv').config({ path:"process.env"});
const compression = require('compression');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');



var app = express();
app.use(xssFilter());
app.use(noSniff());
app.use(compression());
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', {maxAge: oneYear, dotfiles:'allow'}));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  maxAge: 200000
}));



app.use('/', indexRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
//   set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

//   render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});



module.exports = app;
```

Here's my app.js

Comment: /home/vincdgfq/sachalebas/app.js  code please

Comment: I've done multiple curl request and saw that html output is same: http://joxi.ru/KAgEEehE6Ooqml  which means that Your issue is on clientside level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue not with backend.

I've done curl requests multiple times and I'm getting same output: 
[image: curl output]

which means issue on clientside with race conditions.

to avoid it try to wrap all code: https://sachalebas.com/ressources/js/script.js

Inside of:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // here goes all js code from ressources/js/script.js
}
```

or make sure You don't have blocking layer in css that being rendered before image.

Comment: thanks for helping me out ! Just posted my app.js and i wrapped all my script.js in a window.load function put still same problem could it maybe be a problem with the async google analytics script ?

Comment: Thanks so much i found the problem was with one of the css files that i loaded from a vendor (pell.min.css) that was causing a redirection !